# Installing postgres with jenkins using Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, jenkins

I would like to insert data into database in my Jenkins pipeline. I'm running Jenkins and Postgresql on docker. I've installed `Database` plugin and configured it using docker IP as host for Postgresql. Connection test returns OK. In my pipeline I've tried to use `Global Database` as reference for my configured connection, but it doesn't work. So I decided to provide credentials in my pipeline and it looks like that:

```
                script {
                    // Define the PostgreSQL connection parameters
                    def dbHost = '10.120.1.3:5432' // ip addres from docker network
                    def dbName = 'postgres'
                    def dbUser = 'myuser'
                    def dbPassword = 'mypassword@WSX'

                    // Define your SQL insert query
                    def insertQuery = "INSERT INTO public.metrics(pr, info) VALUES ('MM-1234', '{\"job1\": \"1695668520\", \"job2\": \"1695661320\"}')"

                    try {
                        // Use the 'sh' step to execute psql command to insert data
                        sh """
                            psql -h ${dbHost} -d ${dbName} -U ${dbUser} -c "${insertQuery}" -w
                        """

                        echo "Data inserted into PostgreSQL."
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        error "Error inserting data into PostgreSQL: ${e.message}"
                    }
                }
```

After that I got error that `psql` is not found, so I added it to my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y postgresql-client && apt-get upgrade
USER jenkins
```

Unfortunately I'm getting error: `ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y postgresql-client &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100`  which I have no idea how to solve. Could somebody help me how to solve this? In addition, is there any other good way to insert data into postgresql database using any other plugin?